# capitalize first and last name with php

Tags: php

I have a string `$name` that contains a first and last name e.g. `Bob Smith`, assuming the user types in `bob smith` I want to be able to capitalize the first letters of their first and last names.

I have tried this: `$bar = ucfirst(strtolower($bar)); // Hello world!` which only outputs `Bob smith`. How would one make it so that both the first and last name are capitalized?

Comment: let the user capitalise their name, their way

Comment: @Dagon has a point. If the person's last name is McKinley, do you really want to convert it to Mckinley?

Comment: or O'Conner or ... http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I agree with @Dagon. How are you planning to handle names with "van" in them, or McGregor for example?  There's no standard way of capitalising names such that it would be trivial to do so programmatically.

Comment: i suppose it is an exercise in futility

Comment: @Alex your intentions are good, it's nice to be able to automate stuff like that for the sake of presentation.  But yeah, in this case I don't think there's going to be an elegant way of handling this.

Comment: capitalise that: 田中太郎

Comment: Point taken, not that I have people with names like that @Dagon. But I did find a nifty little function: http://www.richnetapps.com/correct-name-capitalization-in-php/

Comment: @Alex your nifty little function is awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ucwords`](http://php.net/ucwords)

Related Functions are useful.

[docs http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/2283/h21r.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/2283/h21r.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ucwords()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php):

```
$bar = ucwords(strtolower($bar));
```

Comment: **Robert O'Conner** would not be happy

Comment: @Dagon I agree but it's not relevant here because he's just answering what the OP wanted.  Whether the OP should be doing that or not is a separate issue :P